# Can I incorporate RedQueryBuilder into a visual query editor as a constraint editor?

Tags: redquerybuilder

I've been working with RedQueryBuilder primarily as a tool for allowing users to place constraints on a single table query. However, I need to add constraints to a more generic visual query and was wondering how to go about this using RQB.

You can see a prototype of my visual query builder here:

http://ordsvqd.bitballoon.com/

I could add a constraints table for all the selected columns, rather like MS Access, or use RQB. However, I'm not sure where to start for RQB - would I need multiple instances of RQB widgets, one per table?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought one instance of RQB. You can tell RQB what SQL to start with and it can handle joins.

Your prototype does selection of columns which RQB does not try and do.

Might be "interesting" in that RQB might want to add/remove a table from the query as your prototype does. As a user I think that would be quite cool.

Looks like a good project. When and up and running maybe raise an issue with RQB to get the documentation (at least) to link to your project?